Async method triggered by kafka consumer gets RejectedExecutionException: ExecutorService in shutdown state
Spring boot kafka consumer gets RejectedExecutionException: ExecutorService in shutdown state when shutdown is triggered.
I tried to use spring.kafka.listener.immediate-stop: true configuration to stop consumer immediately but still getting same error.
Is there a way to let async method accept tasks till kafka consumer processes all messages polled during shutdown?
Here is a sample code:
@Service
public class AsyncService {

    @Async
    void testAsync() {
        System.out.println("Async task is working"); 
    }
}


@Slf4j
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class KafkaConsumer {

    protected final AsyncService asyncService;

    @Bean
    public Consumer<TestEvent> flightEventConsumer() {
        return msg -> {
            log.info(msg.toString());
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<TestMsgEvent>> dailyConsumer() {
        return msg -> {
            log.info(">>><<<: " + msg.toString());
            TestMsgEvent testMsgEvent = msg.getPayload();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            try {
                asyncService.testAsync();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
                e.printStackTrace(pw);
                String printExceptionAsString
                        = sw.toString();
                System.out.println(":::::" + printExceptionAsString);
            }

        };



    }


}


